# find out the root node tag in xml using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing, tags

I have a  xml file with a different root node. The xml is created dynamically (on the fly).

I want to find out the root tag. i.e

*) ns:workflowInvoked

*) ns:invokingService

*)ns:sendingResult

for each of the xml chunks.

Here's the part of sample xml chunks. I have pasted only three chunks. I have many more xml chunks all with different root tag. Here by root tag I mean

*)ns:workflowInvoked
*) ns:invokingService 
*) ns:sendingResult

I need to parse them.

```
   <ns:workflowInvoked 
    xmlns:ns="http://xxxxx/schemas/wft/2011/08" 
    infoModelVersion="2.6">
    <ns:notificationSource 
        ns:serviceID="Workflow1_cbc2c80b_511c_4a5b_9f88_fa789378296b" 
        ns:experimentID="Workflow1_cbc2c80b-511c-4a5b-9f88-fa789378296b" />
    <ns:timestamp>2013-07-26T23:45:37.654+05:30</ns:timestamp>
    <ns:description>echo=hi vija</ns:description><ns:annotation />
    <ns:initiator ns:serviceID="Workflow1_cbc2c80b_511c_4a5b_9f88_fa789378296b" />
</ns:workflowInvoked>


<ns:invokingService xmlns:ns="http://xxxxxx/schemas/wft/2011/08" infoModelVersion="2.6"><ns:notificationSource ns:serviceID="Workflow1_904264c9_1e41_419b_afa3_409b040dc472" ns:experimentID="Workflow1_904264c9-1e41-419b-afa3-409b040dc472" /><ns:timestamp>2013-07-23T03:21:44.295+05:30</ns:timestamp><ns:description>echo=nice work</ns:description><ns:annotation /><ns:request><ns:body><n1:greet xmlns:n1="http://samples.airavata.apache.org"><n1:echo>nice work</n1:echo></n1:greet></ns:body></ns:request><ns:receiver ns:serviceID="SimpleMathServicePortType_greet" ns:workflowID="Workflow1_904264c9_1e41_419b_afa3_409b040dc472" ns:workflowTimestep="0" ns:workflowNodeID="SimpleMathServicePortType_greet" />
</ns:invokingService>

<ns:sendingResult xmlns:ns="http://xxxxxx/schemas/wft/2011/08" infoModelVersion="2.6"><ns:notificationSource ns:serviceID="Workflow1_904264c9_1e41_419b_afa3_409b040dc472" ns:experimentID="Workflow1_904264c9-1e41-419b-afa3-409b040dc472" /><ns:timestamp>2013-07-23T03:21:49.041+05:30</ns:timestamp><ns:description /><ns:annotation /><ns:receiver ns:serviceID="Workflow1_904264c9_1e41_419b_afa3_409b040dc472" />
</ns:sendingResult>
```

**Things which I tried**

If $xml has one of the above xml at one time
I tried using

```
 console.log($xml.find("*").eq(0)[0].nodeName);
```

But this gives me o/p as

**ns:notificationSource **

So then I tried

```
    console.log($xml.find("*").eq(0).nodeName);
and 
console.log($xml.find("*").nodeName);
```

They throw o/p as

**undefined **.

o/p I want is

I want to print the root tags.

*) ns:workflowInvoked

*) ns:invokingService

*)ns:sendingResult

Can somebody point the mistake I am making. It seems my code is correct.

Comment: Would this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554114/find-an-xml-node-using-jquery-and-use-its-values

Comment: Can you tell me how is it related to Java?

Comment: @JtheRocker sorry it was typo. I meant javascript . I have updated. Thank you for pointing out

Comment: @aug the xml I am getting is dynamic I cant use a selector in the find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I did some search on google. went through Jquery documentation.

```
console.log($xml.filter('*').eq(0)[0].nodeName);
```

does the job.

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` search for descendants, here your root tags are not descendants, they are siblings of each other. You could wrap it inside any wrapper but i think you are just looking for that:

```
$(xml).filter(':not(:text)').eq(0)  //=> ns:workflowInvoked node
$(xml).filter(':not(:text)').eq(1)  //=> ns:invokingService node
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s6fuP/)

Comment: This returns me the object. and not ns:workflowInvoked,  ns:invokingService

Comment: So what is xml, not the same than the one you have posted? I mean, it works in jsfiddle. BTW, your xml seems not valid, at least this what says the xml parser

Comment: I have added more clarification in the question. My xml is valid. I just tried converting it from xml to json . It works fine